# Condtionally disable button by Radio and Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, checkbox, radio-button

I would like to conditionally disable a button based on a radio and checkbox combination. The radio will have two options, the first is checked by default. If the user selects the second option then I would like to disable a button until at least one checkbox has been checked.

I have searched at length on CodePen and Stack Overflow but cannot find a solution that works with my conditionals. The results I did find were close but I couldn't adapt them to my needs as I am a Javascript novice.

I am using JQuery, if that helps.

If needed:
http://codepen.io/traceofwind/pen/EVNxZj

```html
<form>
<div id="input-option1">First option: (required)
   <input type="radio" name="required" id="required" value="1" checked="checked">Yes
   <input type="radio" name="required" id="required" value="2">No
<div>

<div id="input-option2">Optionals:
   <input type="checkbox" name="optionals" id="optionals" value="2a">Optional 1
   <input type="checkbox" name="optionals" id="optionals" value="2b">Optional 2
<div>

<div id="input-option3">Extras:
   <input type="checkbox" name="extra" id="extra" value="3">Extra 1
<div>
   
<button type="button" id="btn">Add to Cart</button>
</form>
```

(Please excuse the code, it is in short hand for example!)

The form element IDs are somewhat fixed. The IDs are generated by OpenCart so I believe the naming convention is set by group, rather than unique. I cannot use IDs such as radio_ID_1 and radio_ID_2, for example; this is an OpenCart framework facet and not a personal choice.

Finally, in pseudo code I am hoping someone can suggest a JQuery / javascript solution along the lines of:

```
if radio = '2' then
   if checkboxes = unchecked then
      btn = disabled
      else
         btn = enabled
   end if
end if
```

Comment: Could you be more precise with your question? What specific problem are you having, or is this an "I don't even know where to begin" situation?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for asking. It's an "I don't even know where to begin" situation. I am hoping that the javascript/JQuery solution can be given in full, or that someone can point me in the right direction. Cheers

Comment: Please note that this HTML is not valid due to repeated ID values, regardless of where it came from. If a framework is generating this markup I would have doubts about using it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick solution and I hope that's what you were after.

```
$(function() {
    var $form = $("#form1");
    var $btn = $form.find("#btn");
    var $radios = $form.find(":radio");
    var $checks = $form.find(":checkbox[name='optionals']");

    $radios.add($checks).on("change", function() {

        var radioVal = $radios.filter(":checked").val();
        $btn.prop("disabled", true);
        if (radioVal == 2) {
            $btn.prop("disabled", !$checks.filter(":checked").length >= 1);
        } else {
            $btn.prop("disabled", !radioVal);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mgthuL1u/) with the above + your HTML.

**Note:** Remove all the IDs except the form ID, button ID (since they're used in the demo) as you can't have duplicate IDs in an HTML document. an ID is meant to identify a unique piece of content. If the idea is to style those elements, then use classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you foresee a lot of JavaScript development in your future, then I would highly recommend the JavaScript courses made available by [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/). Although the full course content is only available for a fee, the most important part of the course materials--the videos and integrated questions--are free.

However, if you don't plan to do a lot of JavaScript development in the future and just need a quick solution so you can move on, here's how to accomplish what you are trying to accomplish:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function(){
    conditionallyToggleButton();
  });
  
  $('form').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
    conditionallyToggleButton();
  });
});

function conditionallyToggleButton()
{
  if (shouldDisableButton())
  {
      disableButton();
  }
  else
  {
    enableButton();
  }
}

function shouldDisableButton()
{
  if ($('div#input-option1 input:checked').val() == 2 
      && !$('form input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length)
  {
    return true;
  }
  
  return false;
}

function disableButton()
{
  $('button').prop('disabled', true);
}

function enableButton()
{
  $('button').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<div id="input-option1">First option: (required)
   <input type="radio" name="required" id="required" value="1" checked="checked">Yes
   <input type="radio" name="required" id="required" value="2">No
<div>

<div id="input-option2">Optionals:
   <input type="checkbox" name="optionals" id="optionals" value="2a">Optional 1
   <input type="checkbox" name="optionals" id="optionals" value="2b">Optional 2
<div>

<div id="input-option3">Extras:
   <input type="checkbox" name="extra" id="extra" value="3">Extra 1
<div>
   
<button type="button" id="btn">Add to Cart</button>
</form>
```

Note that the JavaScript code above is a quick-and-dirty solution. To do it right, you would probably want to create a JavaScript class representing the add to cart form that manages the behavior of the form elements and which caches the jQuery-wrapped form elements in properties.